# How to change google sheet share setting for sheet created by service account

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

We are creating google sheet using google sheet api, we want to disable share setting "Editor can change permission and share" please find screenshot in attachment.
We need a way how we disable this setting using google api.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this using google sheet api, i am using java to intreact with google there is one method in class: **com.google.api.services.drive.model.File**
method : **setWritersCanShare** just set it to false.
file.setWritersCanShare(false)